# How to complete concatenation loop with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I need to concatenate the data in range E3:E1100 with the corresponding range in column F, F3:F1100. And write the result to the corresponding range in column G, G3:G1100. I have been searching forums and haven't quite been able to figure it out as each situation is a bit different from mine. I don't actually know VBA, I am just trying to complete part two of a project I was given. So far I have the below code but it doesn't do anything because I don't know what I am doing. Can anyone provide assistance?

```
Dim Subacct As Range
    Set Subacct = Range("E3:E1100")

Dim Subacct2 As Range
    Set Subacct2 = Range("F3:F1100")

Dim i As Integer
    i = i + 1


For Each Subacct In SubaccountRange.Cells
    For Each Subacct2 In Subaccount2Range.Cells
        If Subacct.Value <> "" And Subacct2.Value <> "" Then

            'Something that concatenates and uses i here...

        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Why not just put in cell `G3` "`=E3&F3`" and drag down?

Comment: Because it's going into a macro. And I was going to adapt the concatenation to add -000- into the subaccount. So If I do that then even if a line doesn't have data there will still be a random -000- on each line for the rest of the spreadsheet. And then it will make errors when importing into the database or still require manual manipulation every time the macro is run.

Comment: Hint: You have `n` rows to process. That nested loop is processing `n^2` rows.

Comment: @PonderingOrchid Then you do `=IF(AND(F3<>"",G3<>""),F3&"-000-"&G3,"")` :)

Answer (score 3):

For some very basic code you could try:

```
Sub Concatenate()

    Range("G3:G1100").Formula = "=E3&F3"
    Range("G3:G1100").Value = Range("G3:G1100").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use Evaluate

```
Range("G3:G1100").Value = Evaluate("if(Row(3:1100),E3:E1100&F3:F1100)")
```

Comment: Nice answer, no need for the `if` though?

Comment: @ChrisMack - thanks. You need the If to return an array - the If will return true values as all >0 and that gives the array of concatenated answers of E and F.

Comment: the other ways to evaluate to array are with index and transpose: `[G3:G1100] = [index(E3:E1100&F3:F1100,)]`

Comment: @Slai - that doesn't work for me (I did remove errant comma).

Comment: I didn't test it but it does need the comma, because the second parameter of INDEX is required

Comment: @Slai - yes I see now, I assumed it was a typo. I tried with 1 after the comma which didn't work but blank or zero works.

Answer (score 1):

My personal solution is:

```
For i = 3 to 1100
    Range("G" & i).Value = Range("E" & i).Value & Range("F" & i).Value
Next i
```

Comment: `n` rows, `n` iterations, +1. Note that this is quite likely the slowest solution, invoking `Worksheet_Change`, `Workbook_Calculate` and UI redraw every time a single cell changes, but *this* is what OP asked for.